# Plain PHP mass email sending VS mailchimp?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I've written a social application, where users can register & login.

In order to do so, I must send out email confirmations and other mails like this.

I'm wondering, is it enough if I've written a manual code (which is being run every hour via cronjob), or should I use mailchimp or other mass-email sending websites? I don't want to have my emails go to spam. Currently, it isn't but I'm afraid in the future this might change.

I've written the following:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

// Select maximum 50 unsent mails
$qry = $db->prepare('SELECT q.*, u.*, c.* FROM emailQueuer AS q INNER JOIN userData AS u ON u.id = q.userId INNER JOIN emailConfirmations AS c ON c.userId = q.userId WHERE q.sendingStatus = 0 AND q.sentStatus = 0 AND q.retryAttempts < 5 LIMIT 0, 50');
$qry->execute();
if ($qry->rowCount() > 0) {
    $mails = $qry->fetchAll();

    for( $i = 0 ; $i < count($mails) ; $i++ ){


        // BASIC DATA
        $email = $mails[$i]["email"];
        $userId = $mails[$i]["userId"];
        // ...ETC


        $subject = "Test";

        $contentJSON = $mails[$i]["content"];
        $content = json_decode($contentJSON, true);
        $patterns = $content["patterns"];
        $patterns []= "/{email-address}/";
        $patterns []= "/{user-id}/";


        ob_start();
        include(ROOT_DIR . '/resources/email-sheets/testsheet.html');
        $output = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        $mailHTML = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $output);
        $mailPLAIN = $subject;   



        $qry = $db->prepare('UPDATE emailQueuer SET sendingStatus = 1, retryAttempts = (retryAttempts + 1) WHERE id = :id');
        $qry->bindParam(':id', $mails[$i]["id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $qry->execute();

        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
        $mail->Host = 'mail.privateemail.com';
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = 'noreply@mysocialappsite.com';
        $mail->Password = 'XXXXXX';
        $mail->setFrom('noreply@mysocialappsite.com', 'mysocialappsite');
        $mail->addReplyTo('contact@mysocialappsite.com', 'Contact');
        $mail->addAddress($email, ($firstName . ' ' . $lastName));
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->msgHTML($mailHTML, __DIR__);
        $mail->AltBody = $mailPLAIN;
        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';


        try {
            $mail->send();

            // Success
            $qry = $db->prepare('UPDATE emailQueuer SET sendingStatus = 0, sentStatus = 1, time = :time WHERE id = :id');
            $qry->bindParam(':id', $mails[$i]["id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $qry->bindParam(':time', Time(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $qry->execute();
        } catch (Exception $e) {

            // Error
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;

            $qry = $db->prepare('UPDATE emailQueuer SET sendingStatus = 0, time = :time WHERE id = :id');
            $qry->bindParam(':id', $mails[$i]["id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $qry->bindParam(':time', Time(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $qry->execute();

            //Reset the connection to abort sending this message
            //The loop will continue trying to send to the rest of the list
            $mail->smtp->reset();
        }
        //Clear all addresses and attachments for the next iteration
        $mail->clearAddresses();
        $mail->clearAttachments();
    }


}
```

I use SSL connection and the email provider is namecheap.com
(the site provider is DigitalOcean)

What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: This is opinion-based, IMHO.

Comment: be sure to update / add an SPF record to validate that the server is sending the email.

Comment: It'll largely depend on volume. Anything that relies on PHP's in-built `mail()` function opens/closes a new connection to your mailserver (e.g. Postfix) for each email you're sending - it's not very efficient and it's using resources on your web server. That's fine for throwing out order confirmation emails (unless you're getting **thousands** of orders a minute), but for bulk sends like newsletters, you'll want to use a separate service.

Comment: FWIW, I run [a mailing list service](https://info.smartmessages.net) that has PHPMailer at its core, and sends over 600,000 messages/hour with fairly minimal resources, so it's entirely possible (see [PHPMailer's mailing list example for how to send efficiently](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps), and docs in the wiki). You won't get that kind of performance from a stock open-source mail server though. For me a far greater concern is that MC has a dismal privacy and security footprint, and I would absolutely not trust them with my data.